# EMAIL id matcher-python regular expression cant figure out

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

i am trying to match specific type of email addreses of the form username@siteaddress
where username is non-empty string of minimum length 5 build from characters {a-z A-Z 0-9 . _}.The username cannot start from '.' or ' _ ' The site-address is build of a prefix which is non-empty string build from characters {a-z A-Z 0-9} (excluding the brackets) followed by one of the following suffixes {".com", ".org", "edu", ".co.in"}. 
The following code doesnt work

```
list=re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._][a-zA-Z0-9._][a-zA-Z0-9._][a-zA-Z0-9._][a-zA-Z0-9._]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\.(com|edu|org|co\.in)",raw_input())
```

However the following works fine when i add a '?:' in the last parenthesis, cant figure out the reason

```
list=re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._][a-zA-Z0-9._][a-zA-Z0-9._][a-zA-Z0-9._][a-zA-Z0-9._]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\.(?:com|edu|org|co\.in)",raw_input())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is less about email-matching than about the behavior of [findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall), which varies depending on whether the regular expression contains capturing groups. Here's a simple example:

```
import re

text = '123.com 456.edu 999.com'

a = r'\d+\.(com|edu)'    # A capturing group.
b = r'\d+\.(?:com|edu)'  # A non-capturing group.

print re.findall(a, text)  # Only the captures: ['com', 'edu', 'com']
print re.findall(b, text)  # The full matches: ['123.com', '456.edu', '999.com']
```

A quick scan through the regular expression [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) might be worthwhile for you. A few items that seem relevant here:

```
(?:...)  # Non-capturing group.
...{4,}  # Match something 4 or more times.
\w       # Word character.
\d       # Digit
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't roll your own email address regex - it's a notoriously difficult thing to do correctly. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for a discussion on the topic.

To summarise that article, this is usually good enough: `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`

This one is even more precise (the author claims 99.99% of email addresses):

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

And this is the version that literally matches all possible [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) email addresses:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
  |  "(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]
      |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")
@ (?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
  |  \[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:
          (?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]
          |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)
     \])
```

The last one is clearly overkill, but it gives you an idea of the complexity involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b[^\W_][\w.]{3,}[^\W_]@[^\W_]+\.(?:com|org|edu|co\.in)\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]